# Getting error on starting mongodb

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I tried to start mongoldb and got error like another instance is running. Closed all other instances, but still getting the same error

```
$ mongod
2017-06-06T14:10:42.318-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=22652 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=IML13C02L80WLF8J2.local
2017-06-06T14:10:42.318-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.0
2017-06-06T14:10:42.318-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f4240c60f005be757399042dc12f6addbc3170c1
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-06-06T14:10:42.319-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: Can you post the output of command "ps -ef | grep -i mongo"?

Comment: You "_closed all other instances_" - so you had had other instances running? On the same data folder?